# How to organize data in document based stores?

Tags: rdbms, nosql

I think about using a NoSQL (document based) database instead a RDBMS (PostgreSQL). I'm used to RDBMS and it feels weird for me to arrange the data in a correct way. Usually I would split up the (simplified data) data like:

[image: simplified data structure]

Some notes:

- each player can have as many friends as he wants
- each player can have 3-10 troops
- each player can have 30-100 units
- each player can have #troops * 5 troop units (same unit in different troops)
- fight history stores the last x fights
- player can have ~5 chests

Now I would like to know how to structure the data in a document based database system. I would split it up like:

Document Player: Player, Friend, Chest, Troop, Troop_Unit, Unit

Document Meta: Fight_History

So it will a really big document containing everything which relies to the core of the game. In addition to that there will be a document storing meta data like history data (battle history, message history, ...). Does it make sense?

I would like to have some tips organizing data in document stored systems.

*Please no "Stick to PostgreSQL" or "Use what you know" tips.*